# external panel in jquery mobile 1.4 causes display bug

Tags: jquery-mobile

I thought my external panels (jQM 1.4) were working great, until I added more content to them, and now, I can see the external panel underneath my app's home page.

If they are short, it's fine, but once they reach a certain height, you can scroll down on the home (first) page and see the panel's contents.

The [new docs](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/panel-external/) aren't much help :/

I've tried a lot of variations... but here's a basic example that will trigger it:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="imExternal" data-theme="a">
  <div style="height: 1200px; background: #000;">
    <p>this is the panel, code is tight and outside of any containing page divs.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

*update: I'm specifically seeing it in my app with a popup open, and then clicking on an input field to show the Android keyboard. It seems to resize the page, which shows content from another page (external panel) underneath it.

Comment: wrap elements in `<div class="ui-content">` or `class="ui-panel-inner`. Both will adjust their height according to contents within.

Comment: all of my container's have the content wrapped with 'ui-content'. I tried adding it the panel content, and nothing has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should enhance *External* widgets manually, as they don't get enhanced when page is created.

```
$(function () {
  $("[data-role=panel]").panel();
});
```

Also, elements / widgets inside *External* panel should be enhanced as well.

```
$(function () {
  $("[data-role=panel]").panel().enhanceWithin();
});
```

Comment: This is essential when using one or more external panels across multiple internal pages.. Thank you so much Omar! :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually... DON'T use popups in external panels. Ultimately, that was the root cause of this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting the css height of the page in question to the window height, which prevented the underlying panel from showing below it.

```
$('#page').css('height', $(window).height());
```

Comment: I had a popup in the external widget. Taking that out solved my problem.